# pre-login handshake failed sql server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-6

We have a executable written using .NET 4.5/EF6 deployed on 2 servers in QA environment. The .exe on QA servers connects to another DB server.  We noticed that at particular time only one of the QA servers (most of the time) is able to connect DB server, other server throws the exception as below

***"The underlying provider failed to open... The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement. This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time."***

[image: Exception thown]